# Should I limit the length of a file name during upload in a Jersey REST API?

Tags: java, jersey

There are some obvious validations when a user uploads a file, such as:
limiting the file size, checking the file extension is acceptable etc.

I was wondering if there is any benefit to restricting the amount of characters in the file name? So a user cannot upload a file to a backend API with 10000 characters, for example. Is there any use of this or is this considered an unneccessary check?

Answer (score 0):

The `filename` parameter on a `multipart/form-data` is only a suggested file name. So there is no need for any validation.

But if you are going to use this suggested name to create a local file on the server you must take into account some important considerations:

- Discard any path information that may be present on the file name.
- That the filename doesn't conflict with an existing local file
- And, of course, the maximum file name length of the server file system

To quote the current spec for multipart/form-data ([RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578))

> If a "filename" parameter is supplied, the requirements of
> Section 2.3 of [RFC2183] for the "receiving MUA" (i.e., the receiving
> Mail User Agent) apply to receivers of multipart/form-data as well:
> do not use the file name blindly, check and possibly change to match
> local file system conventions if applicable, and do not use directory
> path information that may be present.

The referenced [Section 2.3 of the RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183#section-2.3) has a more detailed explanation, and the Section 5 details some security cosiderations:

> Since this memo provides a way for the sender to suggest a filename,
> a receiving MUA must take care that the sender's suggested filename
> does not represent a hazard. Using UNIX as an example, some hazards
> would be:
>
> - Creating startup files (e.g., ".login").
> - Creating or overwriting system files (e.g., "/etc/passwd").
> - Overwriting any existing file.
> - Placing executable files into any command search path (e.g., "~/bin/more").
> - Sending the file to a pipe (e.g., "| sh").
>
> In general, the receiving MUA should not name or place the file such
> that it will get interpreted or executed without the user explicitly
> initiating the action.